# Filtrar por fechas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito poder realizar una consulta en el cual debo filtrar por fechas, en la cual tengo fecha de inicio y fecha de fin y que la consulta me arroje resultados que estén dentro del rango de esas dos fechas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utiliza el operador `between`. Si precisas de pasar las fechas al SQL como literales, utiliza el formato `YYYYMMDD` que, en mi experiencia, funciona siempre, independientemente del idioma/cultura en que esté configurado el servidor y el cliente del SQL Server, en resumen, para ver los datos del primer semestre del 2016, la consulta sería algo similar a:

```
select *
  from miTabla
 where Fecha between '20160101' and '20160630';
```

Si los campos son tipo DateTime, podrías querer incluir información de la hora, para ese caso, siguiendo con el ejemplo de uso de literales, puedes valerte del formato `YYYYMMDD HH24:MM:SS`, por ejemplo:

```
select *
  from miTabla
 where Fecha between '20160101 00:00:00' and '20160630 23:59:59';
```

La recomendación es, siempre que sea posible, pasar los valores de fechas como parámetros, pero la sintaxis final dependerá de las capacidades de la capa de conexión a datos de tu lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 5):

En lo personal, el patrón que siempre uso para este tipo de consulta, y que maneja bien si las fechas en tu base de datos tienen un componente de hora es el siguiente:

```
-- simular parámetros con fechas de inicio y fin.
declare @fechaInicio date = '2014-05-05';
declare @fechaFin date = '2014-05-06';

select * from tbl
 where campoFecha >= @fechaInicio
   and campoFecha < dateadd(day, 1, @fechaFin);
```

---

Más explicación...

Si la columna `campofecha` tiene un componente hora, obviamente el filtrar con:

```
where campoFecha between '2014-05-05' and '2014-05-06'
```

... es incorrecto, porque equivale a:

```
where campoFecha >= '2014-05-05'
  and campofecha <= '2014-05-06'
```

... y esto excluiría fechas como `2014-05-06 12:00:00`.

Es cierto que se puede expresar la condición como se sugiere en la respuesta aceptada:

```
where campoFecha between '2014-05-05' and '2014-05-06 23:59:59'
```

... pero, por un lado, esto no me parece muy limpio. Por otro, dependiendo de donde defines los parámetros, puede que sea un poco raro el que tengas que definir un componente hora, y tal vez no se pueda hacer dependiendo del tipo que usas.

Pero más importante aún, en teoría esa condición también tiene una falla.  Por ejemplo, en SQL Server, el tipo `datetime` también puede incluír fracciones de segundos.  De modo que es posible, aunque improbable, que tengas una fecha `2014-05-06 23:59:59.500` que quede excluída por la consulta.

Es por esta razón que prefiero usar una condición inclusiva para la fecha de inicio y una condición exclusiva para la fecha de fin:

```
where campoFecha >= '2014-05-05'
  and campofecha < '2014-05-07'
```

Esto es mucho más preciso y no puede fallar. La única desventaja es que no usa el operador `between` que aparentemente a varios les agrada.

Pero al respecto, dejo un enlace a un artículo redactado por Aaron Bertrand, un guru reconocido de SQL Server, quien argumenta que el uso de `between` es peligroso para este tipo de condiciones: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE CampoFecha 
BETWEEN :fechaInicio AND :fechaFin ;
```

Es lo ideal, ya que en un uso normal no meterías las fechas directamente en la tabla, si no a través de la aplicación, donde las formatearías como fecha, con la máscara que más te convenga (YYMMDD, DD-MM-YYYY, etc)

Usar WHERE en este caso (como ponen en otra de las respuestas) no es productivo, porque para eso ya existe el BETWEEN.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE CampoFecha 
BETWEEN '2011/02/25' AND '2011/02/27'

SELECT *
FROM tabla 
WHERE CampoFecha >= '2011/02/25' 
AND CampoFecha <= '2011/02/27'
```