# consulta mysql para contar y agrupar registros de días diferentes en rangos de horas diferentes

Tags: mysql

Buen día, estoy trabajando en un proyecto y tengo el siguiente problema:

tabla `carreraXestado` lo que registra es el id de la carrera, el estado de la carrera 'ejemplo: estCar_id=3 "carrera finalizada "' y la fecha y la hora de cada registro, ejemplo de los campos:

```
carXest_car_id int
carXesta_estCar_id int 
carXesta_fechaHora CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente:

un día "normal" de trabajo normal es de la siguiente  manera:

- 14/03/2017 00:00:00 hasta 14/03/2017 23:59:59

mi caso un día "anormal" de trabajo es de la siguiente manera:

- 14/03/2017 20:00:00 hasta 15/03/2017 06:00:00

lo que necesito es una consulta en MySQL que pueda contar las carreras hechas por días "anormales" y agruparlos por el primer dia que se compara en este caso 14/03/2017 y que tengan estado 3, de toda una semana para así poder gratificar estos datos.

ya intente de muchas formas lo mas cerca que estuve fue con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT count(carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id) AS num_carreras, date_format(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora,'%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha FROM carreraXestado WHERE (carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora BETWEEN '2017-03-03 20:00:00' AND '2017-03-04 06:00:00') AND carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id = 3
```

pero cuando le pongo los rangos de dias de una semana y le hago un **GROUP BY** me los agrupa como si fueran dias "normales"

```
SELECT count(carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id) AS num_carreras, date_format(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora,'%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha FROM carreraXestado WHERE (carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora BETWEEN '2017-03-03 20:00:00' AND '2017-03-08 06:00:00') AND carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id = 3 GROUP BY date_format(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Espero me puedan colaborar trate de ser lo mas claro posible, ya estoy un poco desesperado es la primera vez que me animo a preguntar en una pagina algún problema de mi trabajo. muchas gracias

Comment: Siendo que un día "anormal" toca en realidad 2 días, ¿a cual de los 2 días hay que asignarlo?  Por ejemplo, entiendo que `14/03/2017 21:00:00` y `15/03/2017 04:00:00` deben agruparse juntos, pero ¿bajo cual día se be agrupar? ¿`14/03/2017` o `15/03/2017`?  Y de paso, ¿seguro que el día anormal no termina con `05:59:59` en vez de `06:00:00`?

Comment: Bajo el día que se deseo agrupar es del primer día en comparación en este caso 14/03/2017. para así poder contar las carreras hechas del día 15/03/2017 20:00:00 hasta el día 16/03/2017 05:59:59 y agruparlas por 15/03/2017 y así con los otros días

Comment: Entendido. De todos modos ya te dejé una respuesta donde te daba ambas opciones. Puedes ignorar la segunda opción.

Comment: sstan: haciendo pruebas coloco el rango del 08/03/2017 al 14/03/2017 y en la BD tengo registros del dia 11/03/2017 pero con hora 14:38:12 y me cuenta estos registros como validos

SELECT count(carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id) AS num_carreras, date_format(date(addtime(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora, '-06:00:00')), '%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha FROM carreraXestado WHERE carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora >= '2017-03-08 20:00:00' AND carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora < '2017-03-14 06:00:00' AND carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id = 6 GROUP BY date(addtime(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora, '-06:00:00'))

Comment: Correcto. Necesitarías agregar una condición combinada más a la consulta para eliminar esos registros (cuidado de que no se te olvide las paréntesis tal como las tengo): `and (hour(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) >= 20 or hour(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) < 6)`

Comment: Perfecto, de nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente, la pregunta se resume en cómo definir el `GROUP BY` para agrupar fechas que tocan 2 días distintos.  Y la respuesta depende de cual de los 2 días quieres. En ambos casos, una forma de lograrlo es agregando o restando horas a la fecha para que todas las horas de trabajo queden bajo el mismo día.

Por ejemplo, digamos que en el caso de tener 2 registros con las fechas `14/03/2017 20:00:00` y `15/03/2017 05:59:59`. Si tu deseo es que ambas fechas se agrupen bajo `14/03/2017` *(con tu última edición, parece que esto es lo que buscas)*, puedes hacerlo haciendo un `GROUP BY` de la fecha menos 6 horas (usando `addtime`), y luego extrayendo la fecha sin la hora usando la función `date`. Puedes usar esa misma expresión en tu `SELECT` y aplicarle el `date_format` que quieres.

```
SELECT date_format(date(addtime(carXesta_fechaHora, '-06:00:00')), '%Y-%m-%d'), ...
...
GROUP BY date(addtime(carXesta_fechaHora, '-06:00:00'))
```

*(Con tu última edición, parece que no necesitas esta opción. Puedes usar la anterior)* Si por otro lado, tu deseo es que ambas fechas se agrupen bajo `15/03/2017`, entonces puedes seguir el mismo principio, pero sumar 4 horas en vez de restar 6 horas:

```
SELECT date_format(date(addtime(carXesta_fechaHora, '04:00:00')), '%Y-%m-%d'), ...
...
GROUP BY date(addtime(carXesta_fechaHora, '04:00:00'))
```

**Edición**

Y para excluír los registros con fechas fuera de las horas aceptadas, necesitas agregar una condición más para eso.

```
AND (hour(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) >= 20
     OR hour(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) < 6)
```

De modo que la consulta quedará de esta manera:

```
SELECT count(carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id) AS num_carreras, 
       date_format(date(addtime(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora, '-06:00:00')), '%Y-%m-%d') AS fecha 
  FROM carreraXestado 
 WHERE carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora >= '2017-03-08 20:00:00' 
   AND carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora < '2017-03-14 06:00:00' 
   AND carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id = 6
   AND (hour(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) >= 20
        OR hour(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) < 6)
 GROUP BY date(addtime(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora, '-06:00:00'))
```

Comment: Nota aparte, te sugiero evitar la condición tramposa `WHERE carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora BETWEEN '2017-03-03 20:00:00' AND '2017-03-04 06:00:00'`. Mas bien, para que las 6pm quede excluído, como parece ser tu intención, yo favorecería la condición `WHERE carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora >= '2017-03-03 20:00:00' AND carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora < '2017-03-04 06:00:00'`. Mas detalles al respecto aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33312/18951.

Comment: Me funciono !! muchas gracias que buena comunidad !!

Comment: Agregué una edición a la respuesta para manejar tu problemita con la fecha `11/03/2017 14:38:12`