# Problemas al filtrar por fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un problema, al momento de filtrar por fechas, el campo por el cual quiero filtrar tiene este formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el query que tengo

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE;
DECLARE @FechaFin DATE;    

SET @FechaInicio = '2021-01-01'
SET @FechaFin = '2021-09-30'

SELECT DISTINCT 
c.FullnameLocal          AS [Nombre Propietario de cuenta], 
c.TaxCode                AS [Identidad],
co.Description           AS [Nombre Cuenta Politica],
ccr.ContractNumber       AS [Numero de Cuenta],
co.Created               AS [Fecha de Creacion de Cuenta],


FROM dbo.Clients c
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerContractRelations ccr ON ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId AND ccr.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1
INNER JOIN dbo.Contracts co ON co.ContractNumber = ccr.ContractNumber
  

WHERE  co.Description LIKE '%POLITICA%LIMPIA%' OR
co.Description LIKE '%/%PARTIDO%' OR co.Description LIKE '%/%PARTIDO%'
OR co.Description LIKE '%PARTIDO%' OR co.Description LIKE '%POLITICA%'

AND co.ContractDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-09-30'
```

Como ven estoy filtrando solo del año 2021, pero en mi resultado me estan saliendo años anteriores a 2021 y no se porque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Checa esta respuesta a ver si resuelve tu problema https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33306/filtrar-por-fechas-en-sql-server/33312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es de lógica:

```
WHERE  co.Description LIKE '%POLITICA%LIMPIA%' OR
       co.Description LIKE '%/%PARTIDO%' OR 
       co.Description LIKE '%/%PARTIDO%' OR 
       co.Description LIKE '%PARTIDO%' OR 
       co.Description LIKE '%POLITICA%'
   
       AND co.ContractDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-09-30'
```

El `OR` invalida el filtro de fecha, cualquier condición que se cumpla con `Description` va a recuperar filas sin importar la fecha. La solución es usar los paréntesis:

```
WHERE  (co.Description LIKE '%POLITICA%LIMPIA%' OR
       co.Description LIKE '%/%PARTIDO%' OR 
       co.Description LIKE '%/%PARTIDO%' OR 
       co.Description LIKE '%PARTIDO%' OR 
       co.Description LIKE '%POLITICA%')
   
       AND co.ContractDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-09-30'
```

Aunque no tiene que ver con tu pregunta, el otro problema es el filtro de fechas cuando tienes fecha + hora, y solo usas la fecha como filtro, lo ideal sería

```
      AND co.ContractDate >= '2021-01-01' 
      AND co.ContractDate < '2021-10-01'
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto, muchas gracias